# Regex python group

Tags: python, regex

How to break down or parse text using regex for following lines in the text file.

RAW Text:

```
"Tommy-PC                   10.10.1.65    ",
"Michael-iPhone             10.10.2.3     ",
"TC-Table01/01/2018         10.10.3.7     "
```

I having trouble using regex how to parse each line into first group as userdevice and second item as their IP address.

Result: 

`Tommy-PC,10.10.1.65,
Michael-iPhone,10.10.2.3,
TC-Table01/01/2018,10.10.3.7`

Here is what I'm using

`(?<username>[^a-zA-Z])            (?<ip>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)`

How to append to join using comma separated?

Comment: Why don't you just split by whitespace?

Comment: `(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*`

Answer (score 3):

[Regular expressions aren't needed here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/), **`split`** will do just fine:

```
s = ["Tommy-PC                   10.10.1.65    ","Michael-iPhone             10.10.2.3     ","TC-Table01/01/2018         10.10.3.7     "]
items = [','.join(i.split()) for i in s]

# Result
['Tommy-PC,10.10.1.65', 'Michael-iPhone,10.10.2.3', 'TC-Table01/01/2018,10.10.3.7']
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that there are no regular expressions needed here, they might be useful e.g. in case you want to make sure that the IP that you get matches your expected pattern. In this case:

```
import re

raw = [
    "Tommy-PC                   10.10.1.65    ",
    "Michael-iPhone             10.10.2.3     ",
    "TC-Table01/01/2018         10.10.3.7     ",
]

result = []
for r in raw:
    match = re.search('(\S+)\s+(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d.\d+)', r)
    if match:
        result.append(','.join(match.group(1,2)))

# result
['Tommy-PC,10.10.1.65',
 'Michael-iPhone,10.10.2.3',
 'TC-Table01/01/2018,10.10.3.7']
```

The regex explained:

- `(\S+)` matches any number of non-whitepace characters and groups them
- `\s+` matches any number of whitespace characters
- `\d{2}` matches exactly two decimals

  - `(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d.\d+)` groups your IP in the form xx.xx.x.x+ with any number of digits after the last dot

In `match` we retrieve those groups by `match.group` with the indices 1 (user) and 2 (ip).

Comment: Thanks Dux. I learn something new about the regex `\d{2}` great tip

Comment: If the last item of the IP can have one to three digits, use `\d{1-3}`